# Matlab multiple subplots in gui

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

I'm currently working on multiple regression in ***Matlab Gui***. I have a variable named **A** and a matrix named **X** with many columns, denoted as X1,X2,...Xn. I want to make figure which will have subplots *(2 in every row)* with plots between **A** and every **X** column. The problem is that when the user insert his **X** matrix, that columns might be 1 ,2 or 10. I think i must make a for loop for X. Is that even possible in subplots? I'm thinking something similar to that. Can someone help me make it work?

```
     cols = size(X,2);
figure;
for i = 1:cols
    subplot(ceil(cols/2),2,i)
    scatter(A,X(i,:));
end
```

the output i want must have subplots with the ***vector A*** in Y axe with every column of a matrix X. I.e. if the X have 5 columns, I want a figure with 5 subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Below is a demonstration.

Quoting from [subplot](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html):

> subplot(m,n,p) divides the current figure into an m-by-n grid and creates axes in the position specified by p.

Therefore, your `a` should be total number of columns divided by 2. This, however, could result in non-integers for odd number of columns. You will need to wrap the quotient with `ceil`.

```
randomColNum = randi([1,10]);
randomRowNum = randi([10,20]);
A = rand(1,randomRowNum ); % make a random vector to imitate matrix A.
X = rand(randomRowNum, randomColNum ); % make a random matrix to imitate user input X.
cols = size(X,2);
figure;
for i = 1:cols
    subplot(ceil(cols/2),2,i)
    scatter(X(:,i), A);
end
```

Comment: that's a start, but not i want to read columns, not rows, and plot a vector with every column of a matrix.

Comment: @NickosRaven Your example image is rather blurry. Can you provide a better one? And what do you mean you want to read columns? I didn't "read" any rows in my answer

Comment: I edit my question, i hope it gives you a better idea of what i want.

Comment: Yes, it is clearer now, but I still fail to see any problem in my code? o_o

Comment: You are plotting a matrix. I want to elements a vector and a matrix. To be plot together in a scatter form.

Comment: @NickosRaven yes, what I provided was a bit off from what you asked, but I thought it would be enough to demonstrate the idea and you would be able to modify the some part of it to suit your need. I have modified it for you though...

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, that works, i'm not familiar with matlab and that's why i couldn't modifed it.  The only thing that must be changed is in the `scatter(X(i,:), A);` must be `x(:,i)` otherwise it reads the row and error occurr. Again thanks for your time